# Can questions be too hard?

Tags: support

I have an idea for a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question and, in my opinion, I believe that it is quite a difficult problem to code in the first place, let alone to golf.

I've seen questions being closed for duplicates, being off-topic and others but was wondering if my question could be closed or put on hold for being *too* difficult (or too easy for that matter)? Obviously I don't want this and haven't found anything regarding this so I wanted to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

Challenges of all difficulties are usually welcome here, Even [ones that aren't proven solvable.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/are-challenges-that-may-not-be-solvable-on-topic-for-ppcg) If a challenge is too unwelcoming, or too hard, it may receive no or negative attention, but it should never be considered off topic, in case those who prefer a challenge want to give it a shot.

And most importantly, it's *very* difficult to say if something is **objectively** too hard. We're varying levels of skill, trying to enforce whether or not something is too hard is, ironically, too hard.